# Tensorflow metrics with custom Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a convolutional neural network that I recently refactored to use Tensorflow's Estimator API, largely following [this tutorial](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/17_Estimator_API.ipynb). However, during training, the metrics I have added to the EstimatorSpec are not being displayed on Tensorboard and do not seem to be evaluated in tfdbg, despite the name scope and metrics being present in the graph written to Tensorboard.

The relevant bits for the `model_fn` are as follows:

```
 ...

 predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_classes], name="predictions")

 ...

 with tf.name_scope("metrics"):
    predictions_rounded = tf.round(predictions)
    accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(input_y, predictions_rounded, name='accuracy')
    precision = tf.metrics.precision(input_y, predictions_rounded, name='precision')
    recall = tf.metrics.recall(input_y, predictions_rounded, name='recall')

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      predictions=predictions)
elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

    ...

    # if we're doing softmax vs sigmoid, we have different metrics
    if cross_entropy == CrossEntropyType.SOFTMAX:
        metrics = {
            'accuracy': accuracy,
            'precision': precision,
            'recall': recall
        }
    elif cross_entropy == CrossEntropyType.SIGMOID:
        metrics = {
            'precision': precision,
            'recall': recall
        }
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("Unrecognized cross entropy function: {}\t Available types are: SOFTMAX, SIGMOID".format(cross_entropy))
    spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op,
                                      eval_metric_ops=metrics)
else:
    raise NotImplementedError('ModeKey provided is not supported: {}'.format(mode))

return spec
```

Anyone have any thoughts on why these aren't getting written? I'm using Tensorflow 1.7 and Python 3.5. I've tried adding them explicitly via `tf.summary.scalar`, and while they do get into Tensorboard that way, they're never updated after the first pass through the graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metrics API has a twist to it, let's take `tf.metrics.accuracy` as an example (all `tf.metrics.*` work the same). This returns 2 values, the `accuracy` metric, and an `upate_op`, this looks like your first mistake. You should have something like this:

```
accuracy, update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(input_y, predictions_rounded, name='accuracy')
```

`accuracy` is just the value as you'd expect it to be calculated, however notice that you might want to compute accuracy across multiple calls to `sess.run`, for example when you compute accuracy of a large test set that doesn't all fit in memory. That's where `update_op` comes in, it accrues the results so that when you ask for `accuracy` it gives you a running tally.

`update_op` has no dependencies, so you either need to run it explicitly in `sess.run` or add a dependency. For example, you might set it to depend on the cost function so that when the cost function is computed `update_op` is computed (causing the running tally for accuracy to be updated):

```
with tf.control_dependencies(cost):
  tf.group(update_op, other_update_ops, ...)
```

You can reset the value of the metrics with the local variable initializer:

```
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

You will need to add accuracy to tensorboard with `tf.summary.scalar(accuracy)` as you mentioned you'd tried (though it appears you were adding the wrong thing).

Comment: Ah.... in every tutorial, they either use a canned estimator or they just do what I have written there and don't mention it again. Doing it manually with tf.summary.scalar--I knew about the tuple thing but I'm glad you mentioned it for posterity--and control dependencies worked, thank you so much!